# Is there a netfilter hook that has the receiving socket already associated?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, linux-kernel, netfilter

The `NF_INET_LOCAL_OUT` hook has `skb->sk` pointing to a `struct sock` for the socket that sent the packet. If there a hook that has it set for the socket that receives the packet? In the `NF_INET_LOCAL_IN` hook, `skb->sk` is null.

<del>Will I have to use `__inet_lookup_skb()`? If so, what is the complexity of that function?</del>

EDIT: looks like `__inet_lookup_skb()` is for TCP only, since there's no `udp_hashinfo`. I'm doing this for UDP initially.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there isn't, but for my case, the LSM hook socket_recvmsg was suitable. It gets a pointer to a `struct sock`, which points to the `struct sk_buff`s in the receive queue.

Answer (score 1):

Just as a small addition:
The UDP input path is a bit different (from TCP):
`NF_INET_LOCAL_IN hooks`->
->`ip_local_deliver_finish()`->`udp_rcv()`->`__udp4_lib_rcv()`->[`__udp4_lib_lookup()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.4.161/source/net/ipv4/udp.c#L495).

`__udp4_lib_lookup()` obtains `struct sock` for particular IP addresses and ports.
Of course on input path at L3 (where was your Netfilter hook) there is still no socket lookups (and therefore sockets). It is the job for transport layer and depends on specific protocol.

So yep in such cases LSM hooks come to the rescue. Also, depending on your needs, you can develop the appropriate kernel patch.

Comment: Thanks for the extra info!